# Are there any non-soy, non-dairy infant formulas?

Tags: infant, formula

#### Background

For a child who is allergic to dairy, there are soy-based formulas. However, soy has phytoestrogens, estrogen-like hormones, to which infants are sensitive*, **.

#### Question

Are there any non-soy, non-dairy infant formulas or formula recipes available?

---

- *[The Mayo Clinic page](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/soy/NS_patient-soy/DSECTION=safety), under infants and breasfeeding.
- **[Canadian Paediatric Society 2009. Concerns for the use of soy-based formulas in infant nutrition. Paediatr Child Health. 14(2): 109–113.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2661347/?tool=pubmed)

Comment: The info you refer to on the Mayo Clinic has no references. Rule number one: always question scientific writing that does not list its sources. Quoting "a recent study" isn't enough.

With regard to isoflavones (the phytoestrogens the Mayo Clinic refers to), it's important to note that the FDA have accepted that Soy-Based Infant Formulas are safe to use as the sole source of nutrition (see: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15113975).

Comment: @Lloydie In my opinion, it is sufficient at the Mayo Clinic to quote a 'recent study' and then have a link to where all of the [peer reviewed literature](http://naturalstandard.com/) that they used can be found.

Comment: @Lloydie I added a citation that was easily reached through the link at the bottom of the Mayo Clinic page

Comment: @Lloydie In addition to the site David mentions (Natural Standard) that actually wrote that pamphlet Mayo is re-distributing, just switch to the ["Selected References"](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/soy/NS_patient-soy/DSECTION=selected-references) tab of the document and you'll get the list of 15 journaled papers they're working from. (well, they say "selected", so odds are there were more than 15, but they cut out some of the ones they relied upon the least to get it to fit in the print copy.

Comment: I'm unsure how the document presented by the question asker supports the position of soy being undesirable for infants.  See, especially, this page: http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/soy/NS_patient-soy/DSECTION=evidence§

Comment: @DanBeale among other things, the paper says that infants drinking soy milk have ~65-400 times as many estrogen-like isoflavones in their blood compared to infants drinking cow-based milk.

Comment: Actually there is a new baby formula about to launch that is soy / dairy free, vegan, organic, and made from 100% wholefoods - that is, no additives or chemicals. It's hemp protein based which means is extremely easy to digest for babies. Last I heard they were suppose to be available this June 2012. It's called "Buddhaful Baby Formula". I'm excited about it myself!

Comment: This *is* the Mayo clinic we're talking about...one the most preeminent medical institutions on the planet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to explore the following: Neocate, Elecare, Nutramigen, Nestle Good Start, Alimentum, and goat's milk.

I have seen children who have been on several of these by physician's order due to various health/feeding issues. Most are formulated to promote digestion, reduce reflux, and prevent allergic reactions. Most are pricey. Some children appear to reject their taste while others thrive on them.

Perhaps one would meet your requirements.

Comment: I was allergic to both 'normal' formula and soy based formulas and my mother couldn't nurse me. I was given goat's milk until I started eating solids.  I don't have any dairy problems now, though.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be attempting to make formula. It is extremely complex and would not provide the nourishment the child needs.

Soy in large quantities is certainly not good for an infant; or anyone for that matter. Low dosages per the soy based formula should not harm the child.

The only option I'm aware of which avoids both soy and dairy is the [Similac Expert Care Alimentum](http://similac.com/baby-formula/similac-expert-care-alimentum).

Comment: what evidence do you have that "It is extremely complex and would not provide the nourishment the child needs"? Not that I doubt that the manufacturing process is complicated, but the ingredient list is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @David Ingredient lists in and of themselves are never all inclusive. Secondly; the DHA/ARA which has been noted as a critical element in an infants development would be difficult to add in the ideal quantity. Sure you can whip together evaporated milk and infant drops but unless it is verified by the FDA you are assuming the recipe is adequate.

Comment: Similac Expert Care Alimentum is based on treated cows milk.

Comment: The link you provided has soy in it.

Comment: @Grumblesaurus Apparently they changed their recipe since the 10+ years that have passed since this posting. A day of enlightenment for all!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer the question, sorry.

Aptamil make a milk suitable for babies with an allergy to milk protein:

http://www.aptamil.co.uk/products/article/aptamil-pepti?tr=carousel

it is, however, cows milk based.

> Aptamil Pepti 1 is suitable for use from birth and should be used under medical supervision. It is a food for special medical purposes for the dietary management of cows’ milk protein allergy and has been specifically developed for bottlefed babies. Aptamil Pepti 1 contains the same unique blend of GOS/FOS prebiotics as our other milks but it is an extensively hydrolysed formula, which means the cows’ milk protein has been broken down, making it easier for babies to tolerate and digest

Or for a lactose intolerant baby there is SMA Lactose Free formula:

http://www.smanutrition.co.uk/sma-products/lactose-free-infant-milk/lactose-free-infant-milk/product-626.aspx

Again, this is treated cows milk, and it's only for lactose intolerance.

> SMA LF is not suitable for those who are allergic to cows’ milk protein, or who suffer from galactosaemia or require a galactose free diet.

Answer (score 1):

From Sally Fallon's Book, [Nourishing Traditions](http://amzn.com/0967089735) (consult your health care provider)

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of SE rules, and so I say this carefully:  this book contains dangerous information and people should consult a qualified registered dietician before using any of the information it provides.

Comment: @Dan It would be helpful if you could be more specific - what in the book do you consider dangerous? Do you consider this recipe dangerous, and if so, what evidence do you have to support your conclusion?