# Looking for a Non Animal Based Formula

Tags: bottle-feeding, formula

We are trying to avoid feeding our baby with animal based formula. Right now my wife is having trouble breastfeeding but still every day we try and it feeds the baby a bit, but he still needs more, so we go to Formula.

Right now he is drinking Similac Total Care (Level 1) but we would want to avoid offering ANY animal based formulas which in our opinion is not the normal way to go, but instead a formula that is better suited from natural sources.

Comment: Is soy an option or not (not clear between the title and question)? Have you asked at the grocery stores in your area what non-dairy formulas are available -- the selection/brands are likely to vary significantly by regional location, so asking your pediatrician or grocery store about the options is more likely to get you useful answers.

Comment: Hi @Erica I updated the title. In regards to your question, here in Costa Rica, they really do an effort on hiding if something is animal based or not. The Pediatrician is also part of the problem since he openly suggests products based on cow milk.

Comment: We know humans are animals. Being condescending is not appropriate. Anybody reading this knows what is being referred by animal so there is no need to go down a etymology path or being rude.

Comment: If you have an answer, please make it an answer, not a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "not the normal way to go"? In modern times, the most typical way is breastfeeding or animal based formula; in pre-modern agricultural times, it would be breastfeeding or goat/cow milk; and in pre-agrarian times, the norm was breastfeeding or death, I imagine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any non-soy, non-dairy infant formulas?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/90/are-there-any-non-soy-non-dairy-infant-formulas)

Comment: @Erik Quite similar, but in this case OP apparently doesn't have a reason to avoid soy.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Parenting has a general policy [against arguing with the premise of a question](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-should-we-advise-when-one-disagrees-with-the-premise-of-a-question/124#124). While this is mostly applied to answers, it is also important to apply when commenting.

Comment: Voting to reopen as this doesn't exclude soy products. This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Do you know about supplementers, for increasing milk supply?  There are two, very similar, one by Medela, one by Lact-aid: http://www.lact-aid.com/.

Comment: @aparente001 Will try them, thank you veru much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist a number of non-animal-milk based options, however none of these are "better suited" than animal based formulas because humans have been giving their babies animal milk as a backup to breast milk for thousands of years (since both are dairy products) and the vast majority of research and product development has been used to improve these common alternatives over other ideas like putting a baby on a plant-based diet.

That said, some babies are actually allergic to dairy, so alternatives *do* exist. You'll be looking for anti-allergic baby formula. The most common alternative to dairy is to use soy-milk.

There are also some other alternatives posted in [this answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/90/are-there-any-non-soy-non-dairy-infant-formulas).

Otherwise, consider talking to your pediatrician. They might be able to suggest other alternatives.

But don't be surprised if your pediatrician also recommends sticking with the regular dairy-based formula. It is the most natural and normal thing you can give an infant if you don't have enough breast milk.